# Spring Controller JSON

Tags: json, spring-mvc, controller

I have a Spring API that returns JSON, the controller methods builds the JSON string using `StringBuilder` and returns the JSON string which can be viewed as raw JSON in the browser.

Is there a better way of creating/returning the results in JSON without using `JacksonJsonView`?. If I just put the results in `HashMap<String, String>` and return the map does that work? I tried it but did not help. Is there any good way, any one can suggest please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring 3.0 introduced the `@ResponseBody` annotation which converts arbitrary data structures to JSON behind the scenes, without your involvement. Just make sure Jackson is on the classpath and you're good to go. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getJson", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> getJson(@RequestParam String something) {
    Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    output.put("date", new Date());
    output.put("input", something);
    return output;
}
```

More info in [spring.io blog](http://spring.io/blog/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) article.

Comment: +1 Good answer. You might also want to look at the Controller **Supported method return types** in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)